# Find the bases of the span $x,x^2, e^x,e^{x+1}$ from the $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is from my exam but I don't remember well. Do you know this that is it standart question? And, can you help for solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basis is not unique so there is no such thing as "*the* basis", you can find "*a* basis".

If $\left\{ x,x^2,e^x,e^{x+1}\right\}$ form a linearly independent set, then you already have a basis. If not, omit a linearly dependent element and check again for independence.

**Hint**. Note that $e^{x+1}=e.e^x$ is a multiple of $e^x$; you can use the Wronskian to check linear (in)dependence of the remaining three.

Comment: thanks. In addition in your comment, also, we need to check this generate of $V$ (if $V$ is a vector space), right?

Comment: Yes and no... A basis needs to be linearly independent and it has to generate the subspace, but since the subspace is given as the set _generated by_ these elements, that part is automatically satisfied. Also: you don't loose any elements in the span when you omit a linearly dependent element.